# Addressbook, data structure in PHP (LDAP)

Tags: php, ldap, openldap

I'm writing an addressbook editor with OpenLDAP backend in PHP.

Now, I'm using LDAP-class *inetOrgPerson*, only. It consists of surname, given name and e-mail address for example. It's possible, that I will need further classes in the future. That is, there will be new attributes.

How can I "design" my PHP script to make attribute extensions most convenient?

Is it feasible to mention all attributes somewhere in an array only once? Would that imply I have to create forms dynamically or use strange things like [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

What's the common approach when adding new columns to a database?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query the OpenLDAP schema to get the available classes and their attributes. It's just another kind of search.

Comment: Thank you. This would definitely be the best solution.